# view-source of a URL not showing the text actually being displayed on the website

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, href

I was working on a project where I will be able to fetch free games details from Epic Games website. The free-games page is https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/free-games.
For example, the currently available free-games are Killing Floor, Lifeless planet and etc. I can see them with my browser view. I can see the text in inspect elements feature... But when I see the source using view-source:https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/free-games, and press CTRL + F to find the text of the game, it doesn't show up. Instead, it shows some kind of these codes.

```
M7.896 0h72.202c5.767 0 7.896 2.178 7.896 8.081v71.232c0 .67 0 5.29-4.529 7.732-3.02 1.627-14.832 6.633-35.437 15.018-1.82.854-2.699 1.075-4.03 1.05-1.496 0-2.057-.202-4.05-1.05C19.357 93.407 7.551 88.4 4.53 87.045 0 85.01.215 82.465.083 81.177A18.781 18.781 0 0 1 0 79.313V8.081C0 2.178 2.129 0 7.896 0zm66.089 72.604L74 72.43v-.381l-.015-.174-.017-.159-.064-.318-.032-.142-.047-.143-.05-.144-.063-.126-.081-.144-.081-.126-.096-.142-.096-.128-.113-.11-.113-.128-.128-.111-.128-.111-.13-.08-.128-.096-.128-.078-.145-.08-.145-.079-.16-.08-.162-.064-.16-.08-.177-.06-.145-.049-.144-.048-.162-.046-.144-.048-.16-.048-.16-.048-.163-.032-.177-.048-.16-.046-.177-.033-.177-.047-.177-.048-.177-.048-.16-.031-.145-.048-.145-.032-.128-.048-.128-.031-.194-.063-.177-.065-.16-.063-.128-.079-.147-.08-.111-.11-.066-.095-.079-.175-.017-.206v-.033l.017-.157.064-.144.096-.143.145-.127.113-.063.128-.063.145-.032.162-.033.175-.031h.354l.145.016.162.015.16.017.16.031.16.032.162.031.16.048.162.048.176.048.13.063.144.048.128.063.145.063.129.065.145.063.128.08.145.062.13.096.127.08.144.079.13.095.096-.126.08-.128.097-.127.096-.126.096-.144.08-.126.097-.128.098-.127.079-.126.096-.128.098-.127.08-.126.095-.144.098-.126.096-.128.08-.127.097-.128-.128-.094-.128-.095-.13-.096-.128-.08-.145-.094-.128-.08-.145-.079-.145-.08-.128-.064-.145-.078-.162-.064-.144-.063-.145-.063-.144-.048-.162-.065-.144-.031-.145-.048-.161-.047-.144-.031-.161-.033-.16-.032-.146-.031-.16-.032-.177-.016-.16-.032-.178-.015h-.16l-.178-.016-.177-.017
```

Can anyone explain me which type of encoding this is to prevent it to fetch? And if so, how do I decrypt it or any other method to get over? I tried encoding detector but failed. It's a pretty new phenomenon for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the page is generated on the client (your browser) side through some JavaScript (possibly React). This means that when you look at the source code, you will just see a html document with no actual content. The content will be rendered after the page is loaded and added dynamically via JavaScript. There's not much you can do it, unless the website itself offers you some kind of API to access their content

Answer (score 1):

It helps understanding if your starting point isn't the middle of an attribute value!

That's part of an SVG [`<path>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths). It describes a line drawn on the image.

Comment: Thank you! That explains